# Regular expression substitution using multiple line records

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a two text files containing a number of multiline records. I have three tasks to complete:

1. Split the text file into multi-line records.
2. Mask out certain fields within the multi-line records such as dates.
3. Compare two records, character by character and return any differences.

I've completed the first task, splitting out the text file into multi-line records with the following regular expression:-

```
$InputFile1 = get-content $File1 | out-string
$Regex = '(?msi)(^0[56]00(?:[^\n]|\n(?!0[56]00|91|92))+)|^(91.{166})'
$File1 = [regex]::matches($InputFile1, $Regex) | %{$_.value}
```

This returns everything starting with 0500 or 0600 up until a new record or a batch trailer is encountered.

The next task is to mask out certain fields within the record. I think it's possible to complete this step with substitution strings after splitting out the file but I not not sure of the syntax. Perhaps someone can give me an example of a similar expression? Advice is also welcome as I may be going about this the wrong way.

Example Record:-

```
050063475327800539226000   74008505059508054855173000000000228000000000000   000000018100344TESTING 1 RECORD SS14MULTILINE      BE 599900000     1009N99203 9 4 0100005
0501            000000                                                          65684160       123456780000000000005 000000  1 510  POSV10080600015          000000000  
050500000000000000000000001810034400        0000 000000018100N              1              000000000000000 0000000000000000
```

I want to replace the first 25-30 characters with  ******. I'm using powershell which uses .net regular expressions.

Comment: `I want to replace the first 25-30 characters`... As in positions 25 to 30, or the first 25 characters, or the first 30 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 questions here so you should really be *asking* three separate questions. However, it sounds like you've solved the first part. I will answer the second part, the third should be a different question.

Assuming your example record is stored in a file and each line of that file is a record, you can substitute postions 25-30 of each record as follows:

```
$rfile = ".\records.txt"
$m = Get-Content $rfile

for($i = 0; $i -lt $m.length; $i++){ 
  $a = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder $m[$i]; 
  (25..30) | % { $a[$_] = '*'} 
  $m[$i] = $a.tostring()  
}

$m | Set-Content $rfile
```

This will load the file into an array. You can iterate over the array and create a `StringBuilder` object for each line. Using this, it's easy to modify the index position of a string.

Finally you can write the modified array contents back to the file, or a new file instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$InputFile1 = get-content $File1 | out-string
$Regex = '(?msi)(^0[56]00(?:[^\n]|\n(?!0[56]00|91|92))+)|^(91.{166})'
$File1 = [regex]::matches($InputFile1, $Regex) | %{$_.value -replace '^\d+\s+','*****'}
```

Comment: The replace replaced the entire line with spaces but the actual syntax looks sound. Thanks !

Comment: Just realized the -replace won't be multi-line single-line.  Updated the answer.